# Time in the negative mass Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, time

I have read that for the Schwarzschild metric solution with $M<0$, something odd happens with the time coordinate. For the constants of motion, $dt/d\tau=e(1 - 2GM/r)^{-1}$ with $M<0$ and $e$ a constant of motion, at $r\to\infty$,  $dt/d\tau=e$ and as $r$ decreases, so does $dt/d\tau$, reaching zero at $r=0$, which is the opposite behaviour to the $t$ coordinate in the ordinary Schwarzschild
metric.

What is happening with the time coordinate in the negative mass Schwarzschild solution?

Source: [Schwarzschild Metric With Negative Mass](https://physicspages.com/pdf/Relativity/Schwarzschild%20metric%20with%20negative%20mass.pdf) Author: Glenn Rowe

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that I properly understand the question. However, looking at the paper in the link you see that the relevant equations are two
$$\frac{dt}{d\tau}=e(1 - 2GM/r)^{-1}$$
and
$$\frac{dr}{d\tau} = \pm \sqrt{e^2 -\left(1 + \frac{C}{r}\right)\left(1 + \frac{\ell^2}{r^2}\right)}$$
where $e$ and $\ell$ are constants.

In the paper, an issue is made explicit:

"Because the time coordinate
behaves differently in this case, is it still correct to identify it with the proper time of an observer at infinity? "

Yes it is: If a particle stays **at rest** at infinity then both $r\to +\infty$ and $\frac{dr}{d\tau}\to 0$ there. That is possible only if $e=0$ from the second equation. The first equation implies that $t= \tau + constant$. Hence, again $t$ is the proper time of a particle **at rest** very far from the singularity.

Regarding the fact that  negative mass "speeds up" (proper) time,
I think that  the meaning of that statement is as follows. Look at the [plots](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oetwowl9kk) for $x>1$. The red line is $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$
for positive mass, the blue one is the analog for negative mass. Here Schwarzschild radius is at $x=1$ as $2GM =1$. The two plots can be  actually compared only in the "positive-mass external" region $x>1$. You see that the "speed of the proper time vs (Killing) time" $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$
increases while approaching $x=1$ and diverges around the singularity $x=0$
along the blue line (negative mass).  Conversely,  it decreases  along the red line (positive mass).

However, far from away the singular region, i.e., for $x\to +\infty$
the two curves coincide.

Comment: Why is then stated that "This is the opposite behaviour to the t coordinate in the ordinary Schwarzschild metric"? What is behaviour of time then in the exterior solution? Does negative mass "speed up" time?

Comment: I do not know, I did not write that paper...

Comment: Forgetting the paper and referring just to the well known Negative mass Schwarzschild solution, what is behaviour of time then in the exterior solution? Does negative mass "speed up" time?

Comment: Well, I do not know since I cannot understand "speed up time"...

Comment: This is what safesphere commented to the original question. I want to know the behaviour of time in the metric.

Comment: I added a final part to my answer to address the issue of the interpreation of "speed up".

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the time coordinate, as described by dt/dτ:

As r → ∞: dt/dτ approaches a constant value of e, where e is a constant of motion. This is similar to the behavior of dt/dτ in the standard Schwarzschild metric for positive mass.

As r decreases: dt/dτ decreases as r approaches zero. This means that the time dilation factor (the rate at which time flows) increases as an object approaches r = 0, reaching zero at the singularity (r = 0).

As you can see, dt/dτ approaches zero at infinity, leading to time dilation, and it increases as r decreases, implying faster time near the central mass. In contrast, for negative mass Schwarzschild solutions, dt/dτ approaches a constant at infinity and decreases as r approaches the singularity, resulting in time dilation near the center.

Comment: I believe this is not correct. Its for the negative mass metric where faster time takes place  near the central mass.

Comment: I think the question is about the behavior of time coordinates near the negative mass solution, right?

Comment: Yes. And there is no time dilation.